# Protractor variable scope with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, javascript-objects

## Background

I'm working on an Angular app which uses ng-repeat to make a table. One of the users found that the table sometimes contains duplicate entries, which I confirmed visually, then promptly wrote a Protractor test for.

## The Test

[image]

### Variable Scoping Issues

While writing the test, I noticed that the scope wasn't behaving in a way that I understood.

Naturally, the for-loop on line 61 has access to `linkStorage` (line 38), since it is in a higher scope. It logs that all of the objects have been successfully added to the object via the for-loop in the promise on line 47.

However, when I move the confirmation loop outside of the promise, say, before the `expect` block...

[image]
...`linkStorage` is an empty object.

[image]

Looping over the object finds no nested key-value pairs; it is truely empty.

### Question (tl;dr)

Why is the `linkStorage` object populated inside the then statement, but not before the expectation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Asynchronousity Strikes Again

The first example works is due to asynchronousity. Because the `.getAttribute` method is non-blocking, the code continues to run past it while it works. Therefore, the console loop is reached before the object has been populated; it's empty.

If you give the asynchronous code some time to run, maybe one second:

[image]

...`linkStorage` is populated.

### Complete Solution

Chain multiple promises together to ensure code runs at the correct time.

```
it('should not have duplicates within the match grid', function() {
    // Already on job A, with match grid shown.
    var duplicate = false;
    var linkStorage = {};

    // Save unique links
    var uniqueUserLinks = element.all(by.css('div.row table tbody tr td a'));
    
    // get an array of href attributes
    uniqueUserLinks.getAttribute('href')
      .then(function(hrefs) {
        // add the links to the linkStorage object
        for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
          // if the link is already there
          if( linkStorage[ hrefs[i] ] ) {
            // update its counter
            linkStorage[hrefs[i]] += 1
            duplicate = true;
            // there's already one duplicate, which will fail the test
            break;
          } else {
            // create a link and start a counter
            linkStorage[hrefs[i]] = 1;
          }
        };
      }).then(function() {
        // confirm links have been added to storage
        for(var link in linkStorage) {
          console.log('link:', link );
          console.log('number:', linkStorage[link] );
        }
      }).then(function() {
          expect(duplicate).toBe(false);
      });
  });
```